# Dice game code gets stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: c++, xcode

I have a pig dice game where there are two modes (1 or 2 dice are rolled). It's played with 2 human players. When I run my program with 1 die selected it runs fine, but when I roll 2 dice it gets thrown into an infinite loop. I'm looking for a hint on where the problem lies and why it was thrown into a loop as in my mind both programs should be almost identical. Sorry in advance if the code looks strange.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

const int PLAYER1 = 0;
const int PLAYER2 = 1;
const int winningScore = 100;
int turn = PLAYER1;


void printIntro()
{
    cout << " Welcome to the dice game: Pig! "<< endl;
    cout << "The goal is to be the first player to reach 100. If playing with one die the rules are that each player can rol as many times as they    choose. just dont roll a 1 or else you'll lose your turn AND all points accumulated in that round. If you're  playing with 2 dies the same rules applies, but if you roll snake eyes (double 1's) you'll not only lose your turn but you'll also loose all your points. good luck and may the best player win!"<< endl;
}


int game1(string playerName, int playerScore)
{
    int roll = rand() % 6 + 1;
    cout << playerName << " You rolled: " << roll <<endl;

    if(roll == 1)
{
    cout << " OH NO! You rolled a 1. "<< endl;
    cout << " Your turn is over. " << endl;
    playerScore = 0;
}

else
{
    playerScore +=roll;
    cout << playerName << " Your score: " << playerScore <<endl;
}

if(roll == 1)
{
    if(turn == PLAYER1)
        turn = PLAYER2;

    else
        turn = PLAYER1;
}
else
{
    char choice;

    cout << " Would you like to roll again? (y/n): ";
    cin >> choice;

    if(choice != 'y')
    {
        if (turn == PLAYER1)
            turn = PLAYER2;
        else
            turn = PLAYER1;
    }
}

return playerScore;

}

int game2(string playerName, int playerScore)
{  
int roll1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
int roll2 = rand() % 6 + 1;

cout << playerName << " You rolled: " << roll1 << " and " << roll2 <<endl;

if(roll1 || roll2 == 1)
{
    cout << " OH NO! You rolled a 1. " << endl;
    cout << " Your turn is over. " << endl;
    playerScore = 0;
}

else if (roll1 && roll2 == 1)
{
    cout << "OH CRAP! You rolled snake eyes!" << endl;
    cout << " Your turn is over. " << endl;
    playerScore == 0;
}

else
{
    playerScore += roll1 + roll2 ;
    cout << playerName << " Your score: " << playerScore <<endl;
}

if(roll1 || roll2 == 1)
{
    if(turn == PLAYER1)
        turn = PLAYER2;

    else
        turn = PLAYER1;
}

else if (roll1 && roll2 == 1)
{
    if(turn == PLAYER1)
        turn = PLAYER2;

    else
        turn = PLAYER1;
}

else
{
    char choice;

    cout << "Would you like to roll again? (y/n): ";
    cin >> choice;

    if(choice != 'y')
    {
        if (turn == PLAYER1)
            turn = PLAYER2;
        else
            turn = PLAYER1;
    }
}

return playerScore;
}


int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

int player1score = 0;
int player2score = 0;
string player1name;
string player2name;
int dieRoll;

printIntro();

cout << " Player 1, Enter your name: ";
cin >> player1name;
cout << " Player 2, Enter your name: ";
cin >> player2name;
cout << "Wouild you like to roll with 1 or 2 dice?" << endl;
cin >> dieRoll;

if (dieRoll == 1)
{
    while (player1score < winningScore && player2score < winningScore)
    {


        if (turn == PLAYER1)
        {
            player1score = game1(player1name, player1score);
        }

        else
        {
            player2score = game1(player2name, player2score);
        }

    }

    if(player1score >= winningScore)
    {
        cout << player1name <<endl;
        cout << " Your score is : " << player1score<<endl;
        cout << player1name << " WINS! " << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << player2name << endl;
        cout <<" Your score: "<< player2score << endl;
        cout << player2name << " WINS!" << endl;
    }
}

else
{
    while (player1score < winningScore && player2score < winningScore)
    {


        if (turn == PLAYER1)
        {
            player1score = game2(player1name, player1score);
        }

        else
        {
            player2score = game2(player2name, player2score);
        }

    }

    if(player1score >= winningScore)
    {
        cout << player1name <<endl;
        cout << " Your score is : " << player1score<<endl;
        cout << player1name << " WINS! " << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << player2name << endl;
        cout <<" Your score: "<< player2score << endl;
        cout << player2name << " WINS!" << endl;
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean for `playerScore == 0;` (within `else if (roll1 && roll2 == 1)`) to be an assignment?

Comment: Wow, you need to practice code organisation a bit. Why all those free functions and not objects holding state? Also, you may want to learn about [ClangFormat](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html). See also [rand() considered harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free debugging service, and you should show your attempts at debugging the code with a debugger or other simpler methods such as debug print statements. You can also test each part of the code separately to figure out exactly which part of the code is causing the problem, and make a [mcve]. This won't be the only time you end up with a bug in your code, and learning to debug your programs will help you much more than having someone find the bug for you. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: Stuff like `if (x == (1 || 0))`, and `if ((x && y) == 2)` don't do what you think they do. The only thing the `||` and `&&` operators do is take in two boolean values and output a boolean value.  That's it. What these operators do barely have any similarity with the meaning of the words "and" and "or" in English, and they have nothing to do with comparing something to multiple values. What `if (x == (1 || 0))` does is that it compares `x` against `1 || 0`, which is 1. The correct way would be to use two comparisons combined with a logical operator like `if (x == 1 || x == 0)`.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple issues in the following block which may be causing problems:

```
else if (roll1 && roll2 == 1)
{
    cout << "OH CRAP! You rolled snake eyes!" << endl;
    cout << " Your turn is over. " << endl;
    playerScore == 0;
}
```

The way you have the conditional written, it just checks to see if `roll1` is anything besides zero (that's the part before `&&`) and *then* it checks if `roll2` is equal to 1. The conditional should probably read: `else if (roll1 == 1 && roll2 == 1)`.

And I think you want to assign (`=`) playerScore at the bottom rather than evaluate for equality (`==`). You already know this, but this is what it should look like: `playerScore = 0`.